# Dynamic sql to convert column names with one row into table with 2 columns and several rows

Tags: sql-server

After searching for several ways of converting columns to rows using PIVOT, cross join etc my question still goes unanswered

I have a Result set which returns 1 row and 147 columns

```
ID | Name | DOB   | BloodGroup | ...... 147 columns
1    XYZ    17MAY    A+          ......
```

My aim is to convert this result set into 2 columns and 147 rows

```
Column_Name | Value
ID             1
NAME           XYZ
:               :
```

How should I go about it ? I appreciate your feedback

Comment: What is your expected sample output? It's a little unclear at the moment. Do  you want to show the column name and column value in the second output column?

Comment: It would have 2 columns namely ColumnName & value respectivey. Under the ColumnName would be all the column mnames like ID, Name, DOB etc wheres in the values column would be their respective values.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish that you cannot with the data in row form?

Comment: Select column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
 where table_name ='XYZ'. This query gives me all the column names under one row. All I need to fugure out is, how to pull the values corresponding to the column names.

Comment: With regards to Daniel's Reply, the ANSWER is NO. I specifically need that structure which needs to be joined to another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response.

I figured out a way of doing it.

I got all the column names in a comma separated string variable. 2. Passed the same string to the UNPIVOT object. By this approach, hard coding of the 140 column names was completely avoided.

Answer (score 1):

I took the second approach Gordon mentioned in his post, but built dynamic SQL from it.  I CROSS JOINED the result of a few sys table JOINs and a source table, then built a CASE statement off the column names.  I UNION it all together as dynamic SQL then EXECUTE it.  To make it easy, I've made all the variable items into variables which you fill out at the beginning of the routine.  Here's the code:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO

DECLARE @MySchema VARCHAR(100),  
        @MyTable VARCHAR(100),
        @MyUIDColumn VARCHAR(100),
        @MyFieldsMaxLength VARCHAR(10),
        @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @MySchema = 'Person';
SET @MyTable = 'Person';

-- Unique ID which routine will identify unique entities by.  Will also sort on this value in the end result dataset.
SET @MyUIDColumn = 'BusinessEntityID';

-- This determines the max length of the fields you will cast in your Value column.
SET @MyFieldsMaxLength = 'MAX';

WITH cteSQL
AS
(
    SELECT      1 AS Sorter, 'SELECT c.name AS ColumnName,' AS SQL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT      2, 'CASE' AS Statement

    UNION ALL

    SELECT      3, 'WHEN c.name = ''' + c.name + ''' THEN CAST(mt.' + c.name + ' AS VARCHAR(' + @MyFieldsMaxLength + ')) '
    FROM        sys.tables t INNER JOIN sys.columns c
                ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    WHERE       t.name = @MyTable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT      4, 'END AS Value' AS Statement

    UNION ALL

    SELECT      5, 'FROM sys.tables t INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id, ' + @MySchema + '.' + @MyTable + ' mt WHERE t.name = ''' + @MyTable + ''' AND s.name = ''' + @MySchema + ''' ORDER BY mt. ' + @MyUIDColumn + ', c.name;' 
)

SELECT @SQL =
(
    SELECT      SQL + ' ' 
    FROM        cteSQL
    ORDER BY    Sorter
    FOR XML PATH ('')
);

EXEC(@SQL);
```

I really can't say what execution time will be like.  I ran it against AdventureWorks2012, Person.Person table (~20k rows, 13 columns) on my local machine and it brought back ~2.5 million rows in about 8 seconds, if that means anything.  The good thing is that its flexible to take any table seamlessly.  Anyway, just thought it was a fun puzzle so decided to play with it a bit.  Hope it helps.

**EDIT:** Thinking about it, this is probably even slower than Gordon's proposed method, but I did it aready.  Oh well. (Yeah, his method works in about half the time.  Getting fancy didn't help me much.)

Answer (score 0):

This is called `unpivot`.  The easiest way, conceptually, is to do:

```
select 'id' as column_name, cast(id as varchar(255)) as column_value
from Result
union all
select 'name', name
from Result
union all
. . .
```

This can be cumbersome to type.  If `result` is a table, you can use `information_schema.columns` to create the SQL, something like:

```
select 'select ''' + column_name + ''' as column_name, cast(' + column_name + ' as varchar(255)) as column_value from result union all'
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'Result'
```

This method is *not* the most efficient approach, because it requires reading the table for each column.  For that `unpivot` is the better approach.  The syntax is described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: I had thought of this approach. However, It is not the best way of doing it. Thanks for the effort!